# iOS - App privacy issue

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store

I am in the process of developing an iPad application for work and have been instructed to provide the following:

"The user must enter their email address to use the FULL application.  They must also agree to the terms and conditions, which allows the application to send us the information they enter and give us permission to contact them about that information.  If the user does not agree to this, he or she may use a LIMITED version of the application for free."

Does this raise any obvious privacy issues?  I understand Apple doesn't like applications to force the sharing of personal information, but if it is optional can that information be used however the developer likes (so long as it is articulated to the user)?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the same thing in one of my App, earlier what I did was I forced user to register before using the app. Apple Rejected it and they said registration should be optional and some of the features should be there for the users to be used in your app without registration.

Then I changed my app model to same like yours, I made registration for specific features and in the registration I collect email address and other type of data.

Apple do not have any problem with that. You have to provide a demo account for your App, so that Apple Review team can test it completely.

Thanks, Hope that experience helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your response! What if we don't necessarily want to set up an account for the user? What we want is for the application to send us information such as: "User john@apple.com just completed the app and tapped the following buttons: A, B and C". From there, we'd like to email them back and say "Hey! You just tapped A, B and C!". Do you think Apple would have a problem with that if we made it clear that we would use their information and contact them?

Comment: You are unlocking the features of the app on the basis of registration right? If you are using information for unlock the features of the app, then Apple won't be having problem, but If you are using it for emailing them or spamming them, or non-app purposes then it will go to rejection side !

Comment: Why does the identity of the user matter?  What do you plan to do with this information?  It starts to smell like malware.  If you just want analytics, why not use Flurry or some analytics library to collect *anonymous* data.

Comment: We are a law firm, and would like to contact users (with their permission) about the information they provide in the app. Think of it like tax accountants - you can answer some questions in the app and the app tells you whether you'll receive a tax return. If you provide your email address, you give the accountants permission to contact you directly to offer assistance in obtaining your tax return.

Comment: @achiral I don't think Apple would be having any problem with that, unless you are sending wanted email not spamming the users. Go Ahead.

Comment: You could also consider an opt-in system.  For the above example, if the app can calculate this information on its own, it can present the user with a dialog that requests their permission to be contacted.  That is more "Apple style."  I worry that you are burying this permission request inside of a 40-page agreement or something..

Answer (score 1):

You will *definitely* have problems with Apple. They will reject apps that require users to share information in order use the app (especially if the app features do not depend on an email), and apps that require users to "set them up." If you make the email address optional and allow all users to access the all features of the app, you will not have a problem.